# Why do some communities not accept converts?

Tags: minhag, hashkafah-philosophy, conversion-to-judaism

Why do some communities not accept converts? I heard that syrian communities don't accept converts. Also in Argentina.
Why did they stop accepting converts?
Also the gemara (yevamos 47b) says we push of geirim because they're difficult like aspachas. Yet after we see they're legit we accept them anyway, and we hurry to do so, because we don't push of on mitvos.

Comment: I think It’s a tradition from when many big Rabbis banned conversions.  I heard a story where a community refused a convert by Rav Ovadia Yosef